# Program acts as if variable doesn't exist, goes straight to "else"

Tags: c#, variables

So, a little problem I ran into here. Whenever in combat, the turn cycles once per second and no matter what, the creature always dies before the player even hits it. So the question is, how should this "if" statement be structured to grab a dynamic health total for the creature the player is fighting?

```
    public void StartBattle()
    {

        messages.Add(String.Format("You engage in combat with {0}", monster.Name));
        battleTimer.Start();
    }

    private void OnBattleUpdate(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (monster.Health <= 0)
        {
            ActionResult result = monster.GetAttackResult();
            messages.Add(result.LookMessage);
            state.Character.CauseDamage(result.HealthChange);
            if (state.Character.Health <= 0)
            {
                messages.Add("You have died.");
                battleTimer.Stop();
            }

            int playerDamage = state.Character.GetDamage().HealthChange;
            messages.Add(String.Format("You swing your weapon at {0} and cause {1} damage", monster.Name, playerDamage));
            monster.CauseDamage(playerDamage);
            messages.Add(String.Format("Health : {0}/{1}", state.Character.Health, state.Character.MaxHealth));
        }
        else
        {

            int playerDamage = state.Character.GetDamage().HealthChange;
            messages.Add(String.Format("You swing your weapon at {0} and cause {1} damage", monster.Name, playerDamage));
            messages.Add(String.Format("The {0} died.", monster.Name));
            messages.Add(String.Format("You loot {0} gold from the {1}", monster.Gold, monster.Name));
            messages.Add(String.Format("Health : {0}/{1}", state.Character.Health, state.Character.MaxHealth));
            state.Character.Gold += monster.Gold;
            mapManager.RemoveMonster(monster, mapManager.MapName);
            battleTimer.Stop();
        }
    }
```

Let me know if more info is needed! Writing my first real program!!

Edit: 
Everything else works in combat, but before I added the method to make a creature actually die, combat would go on until the player died.

monster is defined in a monster maker class as:

Example Rat:

```
public class MonsterMaker
{
    public static Monster CreateRat()
    {
        Monster monster = new Monster();

        monster.Name = "rat";
        monster.Gold = 10;
        monster.Health = 10;
        monster.lowDamage = 2;
        monster.highDamage = 4;
        monster.AttackMessage1 = "{0} bites you for {1} damage.";
        monster.AttackMessage2 = "{0} slashes at you with it's claws for {1} damage.";
        monster.AttackMessage3 = "{0} rats you out for {1} damage.";
        monster.MissMessage1 = "{0} bites at you and misses.";
        monster.MissMessage2 = "{0} slashes at you and misses.";

        return monster;
    }
```

Comment: where is `monster` defined?

Comment: Where do you initialize monster.Health to something other than 0?

Answer (score 3):

These lines

```
if (monster.Health <= 0)
    {
        ActionResult result = monster.GetAttackResult();
```

seem to be saying "if the monster has zero or fewer hit points, have it attack".  You probably meant > 0.

**UPDATE**

*Based on the full code you link in the comments*

I suspect that the core problem is that the timer fires over and over while you are debugging, causing confusing behavior.  I modified the beginning of the handler to just return if an event is currently being processed, 
to make it easier to step through the code.  This would not be needed during normal execution, because the timer interval is vastly longer than the time to process the code.

```
    bool runningOnBattleUpdate = false;

    public void OnBattleUpdate(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (runningOnBattleUpdate) return;

        try
        {
            runningOnBattleUpdate = true;
            if (monster.IsAlive == false)
            {
                // Stuff
            }
            else
            {
                // Other stuff
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            runningOnBattleUpdate = false;
        }
    }
```

This property is implemented incorrectly.  It throws a StackOverflowException because the setter recursively calls itself.

```
public bool IsAlive
{
    get { return _isAlive; }
    set
    {
        if (Health <= 0)
        {
            _isAlive = false;
            IsAlive = false;

        }
        else
        {
            _isAlive = true;
            IsAlive = true;
        }
    }
}
```

You could use

```
public bool IsAlive
{
    get { return Health > 0; }
}
```

You currently set the state of IsAlive directly.  However, that doesn't make sense.  Instead, set the current Health and let the IsAlive getter figure things out based on Health.

and delete lines that explicitly change IsAlive and _isAlive like

```
monster.IsAlive = true;
monster._isAlive = true;
```

You probably also want to prevent the character from getting in a blow after it is dead

```
if (state.Character.Health <= 0)
{
    messages.Add("You have died.");
    battleTimer.Stop();
    return; // You don't want to let a dead character damage a monster
}
```

Note that the user interface project is not currently set to compile (right-click the solution in Solution Explorer, select Configuration Manager, click build).

With these changes, I was able to move south a few times and defeat a snake.

Comment: Making the edit specified returned the same results, thank you for answering though!

Comment: I suspect you may have other errors in terms of branching as well.  Read all of your code like it is a plain text narrative rather than code, and see if it makes sense to you.

Comment: After a ton of troubleshooting, I have still made no progress. It never recognizes the if statement and goes straight to else. Would you be willing to take a quick look at the code in it's entirety? As I have not been able to find resources elsewhere

Comment: I can have a quick look.  Can you post a link to a zip of your project?

Comment: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=cac209cd4cc6296b!7400&authkey=!ADSJNq28bxPba1Q&ithint=file%2czip  Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm looking at the code.  The project RPG.UserInterface is set not to build, so any changes you make there are not being compiled.  More to come.

Comment: Interestingly, I was able to fix the problem in a slightly different way just a couple a minutes before I read the edits! Anyway, I'm probably going to go with your method. Thank you for your help, and your corrections to the code will definitely help my progress :)